# system command not working in C++

Tags: c++

I ran the following program as a root user in c++.

```
 int main(){
   if (system("sudo sh -c sync")!=0)
       cout<<"\n sync failed";       
   if (system("echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches")!=0)
       cout<<"\n clearning cache failed";
}
```

However, I am finding that the cache's are not getting cleared and I am getting the following output:

```
 sync failed.
 clearing cache failed.
```

I dont know where am I going wrong. Can someone please help me with this a little.

Comment: Does the return value you get tell you anything?

Comment: sudo usually requires a password. Are you being asked for the password when you run it?

Comment: I don't think `sync` even needs to be run as root.

Comment: @ams on the other hand, writing to `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` certainly needs to be run as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better avoid [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) for such things. You could just call [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) (it is one of the few [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) which cannot fail). You could call [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) (as `FILE*f = fopen("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", "r");` ...) then [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html) & `fclose` in the second case; you always should test against failure and use  `perror` in failure cases.

So,

```
sync();
FILE *f = fopen("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", "r");
if (!f) { perror("fopen drop_caches"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
if (fprintf(f, "3\n") < 0) 
   { perror ("fprintf drop_cache"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
if (fclose(f)) { perror ("fclose drop_cache"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

BTW, don't forget the required `#include`-s, compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), and **use the debugger** (`gdb`). And learn how to use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and the documentation of every function that you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help..but I am getting error: could not convert ‘sync()’ from ‘void’ to ‘bool’

Comment: My mistake. `sync(2)` cannot fail! But please understand the meaning of RTFM, STFW, & GIYF.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now it gives the error: fprintf drop_cache: Bad file descriptor :(

Answer (score 2):

`sudo sh -c sync` probably fails, because `sudo` needs to read user password. As it is run from your program and not a terminal, it fails to prompt for that password. Try use `-n` (non-interactive) option for `sudo`, and modify `/etc/sudoers/` so that command you need to run doesn't need to prompt for password. Better, do not use sudo inside your program, instead run use `sudo` to run your app.

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` fails, because `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` typically is not writable by user. See my advice in previous paragraph.